# xcrun file shell script code in Mac OSX 10.7.5

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-lion, xcrun

I updated my `/usr/bin/xcrun` file on my computer running on `Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5` by mistake. Can anybody send me the shell script code or any link where I can find this? FYI, I have `Xcode (4.6)` also installed on my system. If anybody body using MAC OSX 10.7.5 can send the shell script code for this file, it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To install the version of `xcrun` that you want you should install the corresponding version of Xcode.

Go to `Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->Components`. Then click the button to install the `Command Line Tools`.

Comment: where do i keep the xcode dmg file to update the /usr/bin/xcrun file.?

Comment: You mean, where do you get it from? You download it from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Comment: In OS X 10.7 and 10.8 with Xcode 4.x, I believe `xcrun` is installed as part of OS X, not by `Xcode`.  I believe there is a package for it included as part of the OS X Installer.

Comment: no i downloaded the xcode. I am asking how will the /usr/bin/xcrun file get updated when new xcode gets installed.

Comment: @ned Deily - Can u tell me where can i get the xcrun file shell script content for MAC OSX 10.7.5?

Comment: Go to `Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->Components`. Then click the button to install the `Command Line Tools`.

Comment: `xcrun` is not a shell script.  You should try installing the command line tools but that may not work.  You might have to look at the packages inside the OS X Installer bundle for 10.7.

Comment: If installing Xcode Command Line Tools doesn't work, try running `pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/xcrun`. That should tell you the package name that `xcrun` was installed from.  Then look in the 10.7 installer app for it and install it manually.

Comment: Can u explain me this : "look in the 10.7 installer app for it and install it manually"

Comment: It's pretty complicated; the OS X installation process was not designed to make it easy to re-install individual system files that have been mistakenly corrupted.  If you don't have a good backup of your system (you should) or access to another 10.7.5 system, then the simplest (not necessarily fastest) way is to reinstall all of OS X.  In any case, this whole question is really off-topic for Stackoverflow.  It would be more appropriate on apple.stackexchange.com. Take-away lesson: do not modify or delete files in `/usr` or `/System/Library` other than `/usr/local`.